# StackSnippets not working?

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-snippets

Getting 500 internal server error in the result pages for Snippets:

```html
<p>Hello World</p>
```

Comment: Works for me here

Comment: Hmm. Running Fiddler shows it's http://stacksnippets.net/ that is failing. Are you getting anything on that URI? I get a 500 error there as well. It could be that it's load balances and just one server has a problem.

Comment: Error for me as well

Comment: OK, thanks - definite duplicate of 284780 - I searched for the tag [stack-snippets] but they didn't add it, which is why I didn't find that one.

Comment: I simply remembered it from earlier. Also, googled "stack snippets server error" which yielded that as the first result. ;) But no worries. The search on-site is pretty dire sometimes.

Comment: There's one on the over-meta too. Not sure where to actually post questions about stack snippets but over-meta seems suitable considering stack snippets aren't local to just Stack Overflow. =)